# Add a column count if values in multiple column meet threshold conditions: R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider `iris` dataset. Let's say I want to create a column `count` if values "sepal" columns are between 1 to 5.

Here's what I have:

```r
iris %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(count = sum(if_any(contains("sepal", ignore.case = TRUE), 
                        .fns = ~ between(.x, 1, 5)))) %>%
  arrange(desc(count))
```

But the output is not what I want.

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species count
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      1 # Should be 1
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      1 # Should be 2
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      1 # Should be 2
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa      1 # Should be 2
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      1 # Should be 2
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa      1 # Should be 1
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      1 # Should be 2
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa      1 # Should be 2
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa      1 # Should be 2
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa      1 # Should be 2
```

I can use `case_when` or `if_else` for the two columns but the *actual dataset has a lot more columns.* So I'm looking for a `dplyr` solution where I don't have to type out all the columns.

Comment: `if_any` tells you whether there are any values between 1 and 5 or not. It returns a logical value (`T` or `F`) for each row, not a count. Even if you sum it up, the outcome should be `sum(TRUE)`=1 or `sum(FALSE)`=0. Obviously `if_any` is not suitable for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  mutate(
    count = rowSums(across(contains("Sepal"), ~ between(.x, 1, 5)))
  )

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species count
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa     1
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa     2
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa     2
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa     2
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa     2
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa     1
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa     2
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa     2
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa     2
10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa     2
```

EDIT:

With `c_across`. To my understanding, `c_across` has to be used with `rowwise()` to perform rowwise aggregation and calculation.

```
iris %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(count = sum(between(c_across(contains("Sepal")), 1, 5)))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works but I'm wondering about the difference between `across` and `c_across`. I need `rowwise()` if I use `c_across` and `rowSums` for across. Any resource I can look up to know more about their differences?

Comment: @Pss I am not quite sure myself but I have attached a piece of code with `c_across` that yield that same result so you can see the difference.